# Why the at-rule use doesn't work in sass?

Tags: css, sass

I'm beginning with sass and i'm trying to import a file with my variables.

it's look like this

```
// _variables.scss
$blue: #0D6EFF;
$red: #FB2B37;
$black: #272727;
$green: #31E3A1;
$lightgrey: rgba(172, 179, 186, 0.5);
```

```
// style.scss
@use "variables";

html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    color: $blue;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

When I compile I get "Undefined variable" and in my style.css the "@use 'variables' " appears at top but if I use @import instead everything works well. I know I could use import but on the Sass website they recommand to use "@use" so could you help me please to fix that bug and understand why it doesn't work ?

Comment: try to use `variables.$blue` instead of `$blue` – Docs: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#loading-members

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use), sass add an implicit namespace when you use `@use`.

So if you write your file using an underscore in front of it like `_variables.scss`:

```css
$blue: #0D6EFF;
$red: #FB2B37;
$black: #272727;
$green: #31E3A1;
$lightgrey: rgba(172, 179, 186, 0.5);
```

You will be able to use this variables using the `variables` namespace:

```css
@use "variables";

html, body{
  height: 100%;
  color: variables.$blue;
  ...
```

If you want an other namespace name, just use `as`:

```css
@use "variables" as myVariables;

html, body{
  height: 100%;
  color: myVariables.$blue;
  ...
```

Comment: Thank for your answer and your explanation it solved my problem ! I didn't see there was a namespace. Thank again

Comment: @Eexy No problem ;) Can you please also `upvote` my answer?